# PERSONALIZED PACKAGE - Estimation and Validation Methods for Subgroup Identification and Personalized Medicine

Tags: data-modeling, cox-regression, model-fitting

I am trying to apply the package "personalized" to a dataset made up of a time-to-event outcome, variables, and treatment status.
I created a propensity score function that works.
Now I should add this function into my fit.subgroup function like this

```
sub.group.num <- fit.subgroup(x = var_num, y = Surv(timeto,EDSS7),
                          trt = DMD,
                          propensity.func = **prop.func**,
                          method = "weighting", loss = "cox_loss_lasso")
```

R returned me the following warning message, like it can not read my function:

```
***`Error in fit.subgroup(x = variables, y = Surv(timeto, EDSS7), trt = treatment,  :
```

arguments of propensity.func() should be 'trt','x', and (optionally) 'match.id'***

Why R does not read my function inside another function?

Comment: Tag your programming language, it can help

Comment: What does `prop.func` look like?